# Value pass to regular expression should have specified character

Tags: regex

I am trying to create validation so the value passed should be in format as i expect.

For example values can be `40%` or `40GB`.

I am trying to use the regex

```
(\\d*\\.?\\d*)([MB|GB|TB|PB|%]?)
```

Is above regex correct?

Comment: How about actually testing strings with your regex?

Comment: what is your target language?

Answer (score 1):

No it's wrong.

1. The character class `[xyz]` is for matching single character. In fact, `[MB|GB|TB|PB|%]` means matching a single character which is one of `M`, `B`, `|`, `G`, `T`, `P` or `%`. Grouping should be done with `(?:...)` not `[...]`.

   ```
   ((?:MB|GB|TB|PB|%)?)
   ```

   Of course it is better to collect the prefixes of the bytes. Also, I think the unit is mandatory, so the `?` should be removed:

   ```
   ([MGTP]B|%)
   ```
2. The regex matches an empty substring, so anything would pass, e.g. use

   ```
   \d+(?:\.\d+)?
   ```

   instead.

Together:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([MGTP]B|%)
```

Comment: @Developer: No, you need `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([MGTP]?B|%)` for `40B` (and it matches the possibly invalid `4.5B`.)

Comment: @Developer: In that case the whole unit is optional `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([MGTP]?B|%)?`. You know what `?` means right?

Comment: @Developer: This is getting ridiculous, how is 'AS' a unit of storage size? (`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([MGTP]?B|%|AS)?`, and **please do learn regex properly.** All the above requests can be solved by simply adding more alternations. I will stop answering comments here for the same pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
^\d*([MGTP]B|%)$
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/X9BDQP8NFT)

Comment: @Kenny, Thanks for the optimized way